# Issues with downloading file from website using python request

Tags: python, download

I have the following code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://etf.invesco.com/de/private/de/product/invesco-kbw-nasdaq-fintech-ucits-etf-acc/reports/IndexConstituentsEquity.xlsx', allow_redirects=True)
open('test.xlsx', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

I try to download the file, but it doesn't work. I guess the problem is that on the website a so called country splash comes up, but unfortunately I don't know how to deal with that.

I solved the problem by using Selenium, but this is not the way actually I would like to go as I would like to use the requests package:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 
PATH = "D:\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

investortype = 'body > div:nth-child(2) > main:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > form:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > label:nth-child(2)'
submit_CSS_Selector = "button[class='o-button']"

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://etf.invesco.com/de/private/de/product/')
# investortype & submit
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, investortype))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, submit_CSS_Selector))).click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.get('https://etf.invesco.com/de/private/de/product/invesco-kbw-nasdaq-fintech-ucits-etf-acc/reports/IndexConstituentsEquity.xlsx')
```

I would very much appreciate if anyone one would be so kind and could help me in solving the problem using the request package instead of Selenium. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use something like *selenium* to handle the "click through"

Comment: If you look at the HTML for that page, you can see it's just presenting a simple HTML `<form>`.  You can see which fields they pass with the form, and it wouldn't be hard to make that same request, but I don't see where they are passing the filename.

Comment: @LancelotduLac Ty, could u be so kind and show the code how to click through= I've often hard times in applying selenium, regardless seleium is there another solution without using selenium?

Comment: @TimRoberts Ty, unfortunately I am quite a beginner in programming, do u have a concrete code for this purpose, that I could use?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a code-writing service.  You're expected to write the code, and then come to us if you have problems.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok, I am sorry, ty anyways.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you maybe tell me if I have to deal with Flask to solve the problem? What is the relevant module that I need to look at?

Comment: No.  Flask is used for PROVIDING web pages, not for using them  As @LancelotduLac said, you could use Selenium, which brings up a real Chrome browser and allows you to click on elements just like a user would.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ty for your reply, the thing with Selenium is u have to use the browser and it pops up and automates by simulating clicks and so on. As far as I understood your first comment there might be a way to communicate with the form directly without opening a browser window and start a request right? What kind of module would I need in order to go this way? Ty in advance. Sorry for my bad English, I am not a fluent english speaker.

Comment: Selenium can run in "headless" mode, without a UI.  If you bring up the Developer Tools in your browser and click the appropriate boxes, you can see in the Network tab exactly what request the browser is sending to get that information.  It might be complicated -- it might need POST data or a Cookie.

Comment: @TimRoberts I solved the problem by using Selenium, but actually this is not the way I'd like to go, I'd prefer to use the request package, but I don't know what approach I can take here.

Comment: I described it.  You need to find out what request the page itself sends when you click that button.  You can do that using the "developer tools" in your browser.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ty the way u described is solving the problem by using Selenium right? I edited the question, look above,  I already solved the problem using selenium, my question is whether there is a way using instead of selenium the request package.

Comment: No.  What i'm suggesting is that you, as a human being, use Chrome with the Developer Tools enabled, then click on the buttons that bring up the page you want, and look in the Developer Tools window to find out what request got sent.  You should be able to duplicate that with `requests`.  But if you solved it with Selenium, why would you go to that trouble?